# Saving Spark DataFrame to Parquet partitioned by Date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, aws-glue

I have huge dataframe that has several columns, one of which is callDate(DateType). I want to save that dataframe to parquet on S3 and partition it by this call_date column. This will be initial load for our project(containing history data), and afterwards in production, after a day finishes it should add up new partition and not delete older ones.

In a case when I omit .partitionBy method, job finishes in 12 minutes. Action example:

```
allDataDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(resultPath)
```

On the other hand when I do this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
allDataDF.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("call_date").parquet(resultPath)
```

job doesn't finish in 30 minutes. I am not doing any repartition before partitionBy, so I guessed speed should be somewhat similar, as every executor should save it's own partition to the specific date? What am I missing here?

Comment: PartitionBy is a wide-transformation which will produce a shuffle stage. That's where your performance difference is coming from. Read more on this for example from https://databricks.com/glossary/what-are-transformations